# How can i move the star with vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to move the star with vectors,i have two vectors,this is my code but when i run it my start goes wrong,how can i fix this problem

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void gotoxy(int eex, int eey)
{
  COORD coord;
  coord.X = eex;
  coord.Y = eey;
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

int main()
{  
  vector <int> tmp(2);//for x,y location
  vector <vector<int> > main(0);//for relocation of x,y last place
  int x=2,y=2,lx,ly;
  for(int i=2;i<20;i++){
    tmp.at(0)=i;//save the location of x
    tmp.at(1)=y;//save the location o y
    main.push_back(tmp);//push the x,y into this vector
    gotoxy(i,y);//go to location
    cout<<"*";
    Sleep(100);
    lx=main[0][i-1];//relocate the last x
    ly=main[0][1];//lelocate the last y
    gotoxy(lx,ly);//go to the last location of " *"
    cout<<" ";
  }
}
```

Comment: You should read [this blog post by Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) about debugging small programs such as this one. Asking the internet to debug your program is not very efficient.

Comment: exactly how Stackoverflow can help us? :) this is my question,i tried to fix this but i couldn't,so i mentioned it here

Comment: I recognize this code :) Okay, please tell us WHY do you save `tmp` vector to `main` vector. Why? If you just want to move two stars like they are a *snake* you don't really need `main` vector.

Comment: BTW, did you study the two sources that I gave you the last time?

Comment: @Dialecticus MY Firend <3 , because when my snake want to change the direction absolutely i need the last position,so i save every X and Y to tmp and then i save the tmp into the main,because of this,is it wrong?

Comment: i told you , i don't need source,because i wrote this game in another way,and this is my second way to develop my last code

Comment: @BartvanNierop my code didn't have any bug or error ,it works wrong because of my wrong,and i can't find this

Comment: Other people's source is useful for learning. You don't have to do everything like they do, but you could study how other people use `push` and `pop` of `std::queue`. The code that uses `queue` is using two separate `queue<int>` objects for x and y coordinates. Your code will be different because you should use `queue<COORD>`. For the snake game `queue` is much better than `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You only look at `main[0]`, so all the other elements that are pushed onto the vector are ignored.

I don't see the point of pushing positions onto a vector and then processing them directly after doing that, in the same loop. This is very confused code.

Comment: look ,i want to move the star continuously,i save every location first in tmp vector then i save the temp into the main vector,and i relocate  from main vector and print " " but my start goes wrong